# Problema con un ejecutable de eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, windows10, jar

Estoy trabajando un videojuego en eclipse y cuando lo corro desde eclipse abre bien, el problema esta cuando lo exporto como ejecutable jar, porque lo ejecuto y a los pocos segundos se congela, ¿Cómo puedo solucionar el problema?

dejo el link del repositorio con el proyecto:
https://github.com/Hectorralop/Videojuego.git

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida al sitio. No veo que el jar que generas  contenga las imágenes, las tienes fuera del jar? ¿Son accesibles desde la ruta que ejecutas el jar? ¿En consola muestra alguna excepción? Si es así, por favor edita la pregunta y añade la excepción y otros detalles importantes relativos a la importación de las imágenes.

Comment: Pon siempre un [repro] en la pregunta misma, no a través de enlaces externos. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.